# Random number place to property

Tags: c#, properties

I am newbie in C# and I doing dice roll game with. I have problem to place random int value to property. Tried different variations but none of them working, just got more or less red wavy lines under text.

How can I place the results of that random operation into property Amount? Google does not helped me after 1,5 hour finding. Where is the problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static System.Random;

namespace DiceRollGame
{
    class Dice
    {
        private static Random randomnumber = new Random();

        public int Amount
        {
            get
            {
                return Amount;
            }

            set
            {
                Amount = value;
            }
        }
        public int ThrowAmount { get; set; }

        public Dice(int throwamount)
        {
            ThrowAmount = 0;
        }

        public static void Throw()
        {

            int numbervalue = randomnumber.Next(1, 6);

            Amount = int numbervalue;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try: Amount = randomnumber.Next(1, 6) in your Throw() method.

Comment: There is no way this will compile, why is the static method `Throw()` referencing the non-static property `Amount` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
class Dice
{
    private readonly Random rnd;
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public int ThrowAmount { get; set; }
    public Dice() => rnd = new Random();
    public void Throw() => Amount = rnd.Next(1, 7); //Random() max value is exclusive
}
```

Usage:

```
Dice d = new Dice();
d.Throw();
Console.WriteLine(d.Amount);
```

Comment: Sorry my language skills, but that ThrowAmount is how many times player has throw the dice, I consider that You think it is the number of dice. Which get three wins first is winner of this game. I made a constructor to reset amount of throws. That's why there is 0.

That Amount is the number of the dice.

Comment: @masteroscar then you don't need to pass it as parameter to the constructor, it will have the default value 0 when you instantiate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `int` Keyword only when you declare the variable. Hence it is just

```
Amount = numbervalue;
```

Moreover, your property is wrong. You will have to create a private variable where you store the value in:

```
private int _amount;
public int Amount
    {
        get
        {
            return _amount;
        }

        set
        {
            _amount = value;
        }
    }
```

If you don't have any further logic in your property then getting and setting the value, you can also use an autoproperty:

```
public int Amount { get; set;}
```

The compiler will create the private variable for you in that case and you save some typing and have less possible sources for Bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Use property with backing field:

```
private int _amount;
public int Amount
{
    get
    {
        return _amount;
    }

    set
    {
        _amount = value;
    }
```

}

And you shouldn't access properies from static context, so make `Throw()` method not static:

```
public void Throw() 
{
    _amount = RandomInstance.Next(1, 6);
}
```

And last one. It is better to initiate Random instance with your Dice class (not static) with constructor:

```
public Dice()
{
    RandomInstance = new Random();
}
```